# small cucumbers shrivelling, turning yellow and dying

Tags: vegetables, greenhouse, cucumbers

They are an all female variety, regularly watered, in a greenhouse with plenty of light. Door and window open every day.  Started with lots of small cucumbers and only 3 have fully developed, the rest got no bigger than 2 - 3 inches then shivelled and turned yellow (from the flower end).  Any suggestions as to what the problem is please ?

Answer (score 1):

Abortion on cucumbers and other cucurbitaceae is quite common.

This is a way for the plant to regulate its resources and prepare for optimal growth during the season.  It might be a fertilizer issue. You may try to limit the growth of the plant by [pinching out](http://www.growsonyou.com/question/show/10482-cucumbers-pinching-out), to help it concentrate on its fruits.

It could also be a pollination issue, as suggested here by Bamboo. [Why did my young cucumbers turn yellow and fall off?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19572/why-did-my-young-cucumbers-turn-yellow-and-fall-off/19574#19574)